# Массивоподобные объекты JS

Tags: javascript

Как создаются объекты подобные NodeList и HTMLCollection ? И есть ли у них преимущество перед массивами?

Comment: [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15763707)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) и [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) являются интерфейсами предоставляемыми [WebAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) для работы с коллекцией DOM элементов.

Основное их отличие между собой: в коллекции [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) могут находиться [узлы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node) [*любого типа*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), в то время как в коллекции [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) - только [элементы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

Так как это *интерфейсы* - программно **невозможно** их создать. Их можно только получить с помощью вызова соответствующих API функций, например, [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/EN/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName), либо как значение поля уже полученного объекта, например, [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/forms)

**Важная особенность** таких коллекций в том, что обычно они *живые*. То есть любое изменение в DOM, сразу отображается в коллекции.

```js
var tests = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
console.log('tests.length:', tests.length);

tests[0].className = 'without-test';
console.log('tests.length', tests.length);
```

```css
#container div::after {
  content: attr(class);
}
#container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#container .test {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

---

Если сравнивать эти коллекции с массивами, то общего у них не так уж и много:

1. наличие свойства length
2. возможность обращения к элементу по индексу.

В последних версиях некоторых браузерах также добавлено несколько методов аналогичным методам массива: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/entries), [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/keys), [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/values)

Поэтому при обходе всей коллекции особой разницы нет коллекция это или массив.

Но если нужно осуществлять фильтрацию либо изменение коллекции - то тут без массива не обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

Это просто объекты с некоторыми методами массивов для удобства.