# как создать html элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Есть метод `document.createElement`, который создает `html элементы`. Возможно создать другим способом помимо этого метода, наподобиe создания обычного объекта? И заодно хотел узнать, что за метод [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element), ибо я не понимаю, что подразумевается под словосочетанием: `Интерфейс Element`.

Буду благодарен, если подскажете книгу или что-то подобное, ибо у меня много вопросов по поводу DOM, и создавать много вопросом будет неуместно.
Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: learn.javascript.ru почитайте

Comment: @Hipster читаю, но там не ответа на мой вопрос, а точнее как создать `html элемент` иным способом по мимо метода `document.createElement`.

Comment: про `innerHTML` почитайте

Comment: Вам нужен раздел: [Добавление и удаление узлов]( https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document) и [Документ и объекты страницы (DOM)](https://learn.javascript.ru/document)

Comment: Возможно поможет ответ на похожий вопрос [Массивоподобные объекты JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599178/186999)

Answer (score 0):

Если интересно самообразование, то вот ссылка на сайт, который фактически и есть онлайн книга. Это
[Современный учебник Javascript](http://learn.javascript.ru/)
, есть раздел "Документ, события, интерфейсы", тебе видимо туда.

По поводу можно ли создать html-элементы как объект... Хм, да по идее можно извратиться, но должен быть в любом случае прототип, который назначит все встроенные свойства и методы, иначе новый объект так и останется просто набором пар "свойство-значение", а не элементом. Но это теория, я не заворачивался никогда этим. :)